# Running Scala under Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I'm very new to Scala and I tried to run Scala project under Eclipse. I used sbt to create one, then ran sbteclipse to prepare it for Eclipse and imported it successfully. However when I try to run it I get

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
```

error. Scala, sbt and Java are installed, because when I try to run the same project via console, using sbt, it works. What am I missing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the classpath of your Eclipse project is incomplete: it's missing the Scala library. Can you double check in Project Settings that the scala library is present?

If all you want to do is try a simple program, an simpler solution is to create a New Scala Project using the Eclipse wizard.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using the scala project wizard and the Scala library is present on the classpath.